# ArcGIS JavaScript Custom Logo

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to insert a custom logo for an ArcGIS mapping app. The app comes with an out-of-the-box way to upload a small logo that is contained completely within the header. However, I wanted to insert a larger logo that 'overlays' the header.

I was able to get this to work, partially, using absolute positioning and z-index commands to place the image in-front of the header. However, once I did this, the title that was located in the center of the header moved to the far left and the analysis buttons on the right disappeared.

The Web AppBuilder template download contains multiple html, .js, .json, and .css files. I used the index.html file to place the logo.

Any thoughts on why the title moved to the left and analysis tool buttons disappeared from the header once I inserted a logo in the .html file? Should I have inserted the logo in another file?

Thank you.

Sample code from the index.html file:

```
        <!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="jimu.js/css/jimu-ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
    img {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 3;
        }
    *{box-sizing: border-box;}
        body,html {
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
          overflow:hidden;
        }
        #main-loading{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #2E3F60;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #main-loading #app-loading, #main-loading #ie-note{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
  #main-loading #app-loading{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
  #main-loading .app-name{
    font: 36px arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  }
        #main-loading img{
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #main-loading .loading-info{
            font: 14px 'arial';
            margin-top: 50px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        #main-loading .loading-info .loading{
            width: 260px;
            height: 4px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            background-color: #15203B;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #main-loading .loading-info .loading-progress{
            height: 4px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            background-color: #ABB2BF;
        }
        #main-loading #ie-note {
    width: 586px;
    height: 253px;
    background-image: url('images/notes.png');
    padding: 0 30px 40px 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #596679;
  }
  #ie-note .hint-title{
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 48px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #ie-note .hint-img{
    background-image: url('images/hint.png');
    background-position: left;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #ie-note span{
    display: block;
    line-height: 14px;
  }
        #main-page{
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }

        #jimu-layout-manager{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you used absolute positioning, and now there's nothing to "push" the text to the right. Just put the right margin on the title text element and you're good to go.

See this:

```css
img {height: 60px;}
span {height: 60px;display: inline-block;}
#p {position:absolute;}
#o {margin-left: 30px;}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.mariogame.info/images/icon-facebook.png" id="p" /><span>Absolutely positioned</span>
<hr />
<img src="http://www.mariogame.info/images/icon-facebook.png" /><span>Normally positioned</span>
<hr />
<img src="http://www.mariogame.info/images/icon-facebook.png" /><span id="o">Absolutely positioned - text offset</span>
```

Comment: That worked for the text. I was able to locate the title element in the config.json file and set the margin past the newly inserted logo. However the widgets/analysis tool buttons are still missing that were initially on the right side of the page. There might be a container for the widgets, but I haven't located it yet.

Is there another command I can use to insert the logo that would not mess with the entire header?

Comment: Not sure I could help you with that without seeing it... Are you sure you haven't modifyed some CSS that those widgets use?

Comment: I have modified CSS that the widgets use, but that was only for informational purposes once the widget was selected. I can remove the custom logo or even set it to 'relative' and the widgets will reappear intact. If set to relative, the logo is at the top of the page and the app is pushed below it. Is there anyway I could share some of the code with you? New to the site and to web development.

Comment: You can add the relevant code to your question and/or make a working code snippet that reproduces the example.

Comment: I have inserted same code above. I inserted the first few lines, leading with img. I also inserted the following between the body tags. <img src="images\_map_logo1.png" width="150" height="90">